# Simple algorithm to go through all permutations

Tags: combinations, permutation, combinatorics

Let's say we have an array { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 }
I want to go through every possible combination while fulfilling these requirements:

- Do not copy first array anywhere
- Every single iteration has to be made sawpping only two elements, for instance, if we have 
  112233 we can go to 121233 112323 because only one swap is needed for that, but NOT 332211 because it needs more than one swap

Yes, this is possible, I've tried programming myself to detect such sequences but I get a wacky pattern like (ones symbolize swaps and 0 symbolizes unchanged elements):

- 011000
- 001100
- 110000

etc and I can't find any easy formula which would allow me to iterate through every permutation algorithmically.

Comment: Permutations with partial repetitions isn't exactly simple, in my experience.  You could have a look at this piece of code https://github.com/ctrimble/combinatorics/blob/master/combinatorics/src/main/java/com/xiantrimble/combinatorics/Permutations.java .  It does a minimum change order if k = the total number of elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Any Language) Find all permutations of elements in a vector using swapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272570/any-language-find-all-permutations-of-elements-in-a-vector-using-swapping)